# intelli j output not generated by build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to build a [JDBC driver for neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc), but no out directory has been created on build.

I downloaded IntelliJ and the current JDK and cloned the repo. I can see the source and run tests: all of which succeed. I assume that step was successful.

Initially on build I got warnings saying to try running build with -xlint:unchecked so I added that under compiler settings additional command line parameters and rebuild. So far so good, I now get warning messages.

The warnings are unchecked method invocations, unchecked generic array creation, unchecked conversions, or deprecated function calls. Seems like pedantic issues that shouldn't actually be problems since the tests pass. (unless in this context deprecated means actually incompatible with current compiler?)

I checked the project structure and the compiler output is set to project_home/out, but that has not been created by the builds...

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using Maven to build/package your project, check the `target` folder

Comment: Thanks @ochi there is a .class file there - back to the drawing board as I was expecting a jar, clearly running the wrong operation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a module specific output path is used in IntelliJ. This can be found under

> Project Settings -> Modules -> Path

and there is a radio button for "Use module compile output path".

As @ochi already mentioned: usually the output folder for maven projects is `target`.